# use variable for redirection: 2>/dev/null

Tags: permissions, null, find

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to redirect the 'permission denied' message when using find so I tried to store a variable in my .profile like so:

```
null='2>/dev/null'
```

If I execute find like this to find all html files:

```
find / -name '*.html' `$null`
```

it works perfectly, what I'm wondering is there any shorter way to do this without creating a bash script?

Comment: In terms of workflow for me? Not really, sorry for the bad nomenclature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guy hacked together a script, [qfind](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=992857). No replies nor have I tested it, so good luck. :)